# How to get a specific line in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a certain line in Python but I am stuck.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pythonforbeginners.com/')
info = response.info()
html = response.read()
# do something
response.close()  # best practice to close the file

if "x" in str(info):
print str(info)

raw_input()
```

I am trying to just get a line to display the type of server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to treat `info` as a string? If not, this should work pretty well:

```
for h in info.headers:
  if h.startswith('Server'):
    print h
```

Comment: @MichelleMoya - Actually, Mr.C's answer is even better. You can access the headers directly by name in dictionary style. In other words, you can simply do it this way: `print info['server']`

Answer (score 1):

I guess what your line is meaning a line in http header.
You can get the http header by following code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pythonforbeginners.com/')
info = response.info()
html = response.read()
# do something
response.close()  # best practice to close the file
# this is how to process the http header
for key in info :
    print key, info[key] 

raw_input()
```

or you can convert the info to string and split by \r\n(http header is separate by \r\n) as follow

```
for line in str(info).split("\r\n") :
    print line, "=="
```